# iptables rules confusion, nat PREROUTING

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, linux-networking

Im struggling to understand exactly what these set of iptables rules do.

Does port 22 get the packet AND port 2222 gets a copy of it as well?
Or does the packet get redirected to port 2222 skipping port 22?
Can someone please explain to me what these set of rules do in detail? thanks in advance!

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 2222
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only the local process listening on port `2222` will receive the packet. If it replies, the reverse translation will take place, and outgoing `reply` packet will be out from port `22`.

Fourth rule will make *any* encountered packets destined to port `22` to be re-routed to your local port `2222`, even if they weren't meant to be for this machine. Since you don't have any other match criteria, it'll be so for anyone, except for connections outgoing from this machine.

In effect, this intercepts any pass-through SSH traffic. If somebody is set this system as their gateway and try to connect to any SSH service outside the LAN, they'll end up connecting to your service running on port `2222` instead. If they were already established the trust (have the real server's key in the `known_hosts` file, or it is is properly published with DNSSEC), their attempt will be rejected by their client with the proper warning about ongoing man-in-the-middle attack (which this rule essentially looks like).

Please, consult the [Netfilter packet flow diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg).

By the way, you *don't need* to enable ip forwarding in this case, because the packet don't need be forwarded (even if it has to be forwarded if there was no `REDIRECT` rule). And you don't need do to anything with the `FORWARD` chain, because it isn't traversed. So first and second commands are redundant. After the `nat` table, the packet is re-targeted to the local machine; when routing decision takes place, the packet is sent to the `INPUT` chain. This is where you can control this packet, and the packet there will be already translated to the port `2222`, so rule in your third command is correct.